# FileNotFoundException with XmlSerializers in application built using Spoon Studio .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xml-serialization, clr4.0

I'm getting the following exception in our virtualized application packaged using Spoon Studio and .Net 4.0

```
Exception='System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\temp\Serialization\mf3je3jx.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'file:///C:\temp\Serialization\mf3je3jx.dll'
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity)
   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults.get_CompiledAssembly()
   at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
```

This was working fine till we were using .Net 3.5 but after migrating to .Net 4.0 package we've started seeing this error.

I understand that the one way to solve this is to pre-generate XmlSerializers but in our case we've multiple add-ins which also needs to be rebuilt and we want to avoid doing that.

**My question is why is this happening at all? Why is runtime not able to generate the serializers at runtime?** I can see .cs and .out files being generated in the temp directory (dll is also generated momentarily and deleted immediately).

If I run my application without virtualization it works fine and able to build and load in-memory serializers. User running the application is same in both of the cases.

Any suggestion are welcomed.

> It's a separate problem but I'm unable to debug this within VS or
>   windbg (I get clr version mismatch error b/w VS and Application)
>
> reason being: installing VS12/.Net 4.5 on the machine upgrades the CLR
>   version number to 4.0.30319.17929 whereas application uses
>   4.0.30319.1. and VS doesn't allow me to attach to this application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've found the issue.

Default .Net Image used by Spoon Studio for .Net 4.0 doesn't have all the required assemblies in it.

This is a bug in Spoon Studio. I got it working by getting a new custom image  from the SpoonStudio team.